# Firefox not registering onclick event handler

Tags: events, firefox, handler

Below are two snips of code for assigning an event handler for an onclick event. Version One works in IE, FF, Safari and Chrome. Version Two works in IE, Safari and Chrome, but not in FF. In Version One, I register the event handler in the markup. In Version Two, I use a newer, and supposedly more robust, method for registering the event handler.

Using firebug, it looks like the onclick event handler is not getting registered, though I cannot see why not. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

```
***************  Version One  ******************************
< script type="text/javascript">

function handler()
{
    // do something here
}

</script>

< a id="playerFive" class="player" onclick="handler()">
    < img src="./images/speakerIcon25pxFFF4E0.png" alt=""/>
</a>
************************************************************


***************  Version Two  ******************************
< script type="text/javascript">

function handler()
{
    // do something here
}

</script>

< a id="playerFive" class="player">
    < img src="./images/speakerIcon25pxFFF4E0.png" alt=""/>
</a>

< script type="text/javascript">

playerFive.onclick = handler;

< /script>
************************************************************
```

Comment: Actually your second version is the same as the first one. It is not "newer" or "more robust", you just set the listener via JavaScript instead in the markup. The new way would be to use `addEventListener`. Useful information: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

FF does not allow you to access DOM elements as javascript variables named by their ID.

You need to use `getElementById` instead.

Comment: +1 Wow, i wasn't aware that any browser did... but i suppose i tried not to write JS in the bad old days of IE<=6 where much of this madness no doubt originated

Answer (score 0):

in the last script block, `playerFive` is never defined anywhere, you probably want

```
document.getElementById('playerFive').onclick=handler;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
 if(document.all)// For IE
 {   
       document.getElementById('playerFive').attachEvent('onclick',handler);
 }
 else // For FF
 {
       document.getElementById('playerFive').addEventListener('click',handler,false);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() { 
        var div = document.getElementById("dvClickMe");
        if(div.attachEvent)
            div.attachEvent('onclick', sayHello); 
        else
            div.setAttribute('onclick', 'sayHello()');
    }
    function sayHello() { alert("Hello!"); }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="dvClickMe">Click me!</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The above code is working on IE8 and FF 3.6.10